"In which bar shall we go?" vs. "Which bar shall we go to?"
Which is better?

In which bar shall we go?

Which bar shall we go to?


A friend of mine has told me that "In which bar shall we go?" might be too formal. Is that true?

You didn't include the other two permutations: "To which bar shall we go?" and "Which bar shall we go in?" Are you asking about the preposition itself, or the position of the prepositional element?

Note that "In which bar shall we go?" isn't "formal". It's just clumsy and unlikely. There are probably still a few people who think "To whom am I speaking?" on the telephone is more "formally correct" than "Who am I speaking to?" But they're idiots anyway, whose diction is stuck in the Victorian era, so take no notice of them.

@FumbleFingers OK, it's clumsy. But is it grammatically correct? Is there a rule that allows this word order?

Thanks a lot, FumbleFingers

If it was syntactically invalid, I'd have said so. It's just idiomatically unlikely. The more so with in as the fronted preposition. Note that into or to are more likely prepositions anyway, but all "fronted" versions are uncommon compared to putting the preposition at the end, whichever is used. There's not really much to choose between the three alternative final prepositions in "Which bar shall we go in / to / into?", but I personally might be more inclined to use to if we have to travel some distance, or in / into if standing between two bars.

I hope my students will excuse my mistake.

Interesting. When I choose the "regsiter" tag it displays as "formality". Who did that?

Prepositions are quirky. In English, we don't go in bars, we go to them. In French, you travel in France, but inside Paris. Point is, no universal right or wrong, but colloquial to each language. A dictionary might not tell you.

@YosefBaskin - I went in a bar about three hours ago; after 45 minutes, and a gin and tonic, I came out again.

Steady, @FumbleFingers, you may count me among those whom you dismiss as idiots. I presume that was to disabuse the OP of any sense of a necessity to adopt the usage you scorn. But in your manner of dismissing such a prescription you ended up expressing yourself thoroughly prescriptively.

@PaulTanenbaum: My comment was addressed to the OP and other learners. If as a native speaker you think "To whom am I speaking?" on the telephone is more "formally correct" than "Who am I speaking to?" then good luck to you. But I really don't see the point of burdening today's learners with such outdated usages. It's not about disabusing the OP of any sense of a necessity to adopt the usage - it's about avoiding adding to learners' problems by not even telling them about how people used to talk, since they should never need to copy that usage.

I agree, @FumbleFingers, that the notion that it’s more formally correct is misguided. So though I use it, I don’t claim that it’s correcter. But describing those who do as “idiots” is name calling, and I find it harsh beyond what’s appropriate in this forum.

@PaulTanenbaum: Perhaps I didn't phrase my earlier comment very well. I wasn't particularly thinking that it might be read by people who do still use the form anyway, so I wasn't all that careful. As a general principle I rarely object to anything native speakers say (though it does sometimes irk me to hear otherwise well-spoken people clearly enunciate something they would of thought! :). The object of my flippant dismissal wasn't people who for whatever reason still use that "telephone voice" cliche. It was people who claim it's "correct", and encourage learners to do likewise!

In American English, if you are asking about choosing a bar where you can have a few drinks at a casual get-together:

Which bar should we go to?

"go to" is used with destinations.
If you are, say, in a section of a city with multiple bars all in the same vicinity, perhaps even next to one another, so that you can see them in front of you, and the question is which one to set foot in:

Which bar should we go into?

The register of these questions is casual and conversational.

In which bar shall we go.

In American English, that question would sound oddly stilted.  In which room shall we meet? on the other hand would sound fine.

A big thank you to all of you.
